# WebSphere and updating cookie information

Tags: websphere, cookie

After updating cookie information (name and path) on all my Application Servers in WebSphere and recycling the cluster, the application stopped working correctly and wouldn't allow people to log in.

My question is, does the global webserver plugin configuration also have to be updated after updating the cookie information (name and/or path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSESSIONID cookie? Then, yes. The plugin is what routes requests to servers based on the session ID, so it has to know the cookie information.

Here's an example from our `plugin-cfg.xml`

```
<Uri AffinityCookie="JSESSIONID" AffinityURLIdentifier="jsessionid" Name="/webapp/*"/>
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  I would up vote it but I don't have enough rep.